# Prevent writes from primary farm to DR database after failover?

Tags: sql-server, 2019, disaster-recovery

I have two SharePoint farms, an active and a DR farm, using SQL Availability groups to sync content and some service DBs. In the event of a manual failover, how do I prevent the primary farm from trying to write anything to the now-active databases that are now being used by the DR farm?

More details: I have a three node AOAG, nodes A and B are in the main site and are in sync mode, node C is in the DR site and is an async node. The primary farm was configured with the listener name, so sync-failovers are working perfectly between the sync nodes A and B. The DR farm is configured with a local SQL alias to the read-only async node, so the DR farm will never try to write anything directly to the SQL databases in the main site. After a failover, Node C becomes read-write, and so the DR farm is then in read-write mode, which is great. But how do I prevent the Main farm from trying to write anything to the now active node C?

Comment: You can write a powershell script to set all SharePoint database to read-only when in failover mode, but then you'd have to switch it back:  https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/01/set-sharepoint-content-database-to-read-only-using-powershell.html

Comment: I would prefer to keep the DR farm in read/write mode to support users.

Comment: I am confused, if it fails-over to Node C, the only way for the Farm to be read-write is for Node C to be read-write.   How can a farm be in read-write if its active SQL Node is not?

Comment: There are two farms: the dr farm should be read/write with node C (since the AG failed over, node C will be read/write), the main farm should be read-only.